# Можно ли изменить графический API unity внутри игры?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

собственно, в чём суть вопроса, делаю игру и хочется добавить выбор графического API в меню игры. Directx11 или 12. Можно как то это сделать или нет ? Попробовал через unityeditor. Rendering.GraphicsDeviceType и ничего. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ok Google: unity3d change graphical api runtime... [SetGraphicsAPIs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.SetGraphicsAPIs.html)

Comment: Люди на форумах пишут, что это только работает в UnityEditor, в самой игре после компиляции ничего не происходит.

Comment: Да, `PlayerSettings` доступна только с `using UnityEditor`. Других инструментов поиск не выдает, судя по всему их просто нет.

Comment: Есть, но через батник, а это неудобно, ладно, откажусь от этого, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Судя по документации `SetGraphicsAPIs` смысла действительно нет, он выбирает api не случайным образом.